# Microsoft Graph API - 503 ErrorServiceUnavailable

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Microsoft Graph API for track my changes in some events in a calendar.
Currently, I get an HTTP 503 error in the endpoint: **/me/calendarView/delta**.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorServiceUnavailable",
        "message": "Active Directory operation did not succeed. Try again later.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "0d70abca-dba6-4c27-9e99-2fa6cc6eb731",
            "date": "2018-10-09T13:27:46"
        }
    }
}
```

I thought it was my client, but I tried the [example request](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_events) on [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and I got the same.
Anyone has faced the same issue? Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: I have tried this, and it works. And my request URL like this:`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarView/delta?startDateTime=2016-12-01T00:00:00Z&endDateTime=2018-12-30T00:00:00Z`

Comment: I tried the same request and it didn't work for me. I got the same error "ErrorServiceUnavailable"

Comment: To clarify, are you seeing the error in Graph Explorer when signed in as your account and running the sample for Delta.

Comment: That's correct. I see the error running the sample request signed in with my personal account

Answer (score 2):

I can't upvote this or comment on this due to the reputation limit but we are seeing the same issue with some of our users.

We are hitting the endpoint: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/<redacted>/messages/delta`

For this particular user, 
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders` and
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/<redacted>/childFolders`
work.

But, asking for the messages with `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/<redacted>/messages/delta` for a folder returns the error posted by OP